# How do I set error to dynamically created elements?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Object> dynamic_arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am storing all the programatically created elements into this `arraylist`:

```
EditText myEditText = new EditText(candidate_registration.this);
myEditText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
myEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-smallcaps", Typeface.NORMAL));
myEditText.setHint("name");
dynamic_arr.add(myEditText);
parent.addView(myEditText);

AppCompatSpinner spin = new AppCompatSpinner(candidate_registration.this, Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
spin.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<>();
spinnerArray.add("A");
spinnerArray.add("B");
spinnerArray.add("C");
spin.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
dynamic_arr.add(spin);
parent.addView(spin);

//In this way I am creating multiple elements and storing them into the arraylist
```

Now I want to `setError()` in each of the elements if their respective values are empty and remove the error otherwise.

```
for(Object o: dynamic_arr){
    //How do I proceed?
}
```

How do I proceed? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use explicit types for collections if possible. Your problem is, that you implicitly cast your custom class to objects of the object class, which don't have your method.
Either cast the objects in the loop to your class

```
YourClass element = (YourClass) o;
element.setError
```

Or use an explicit type for your collection.

```
ArrayList<YourClass>
```